# could not get provisioner inherent data; injecting default data err=ClosedChannelAwaitingInherentData

Tags: finalization

I have a chain with 4 validators. When I chilled 1 old validator and added 1 new, the chain has stopped finalization.
Nodes show the following error:

```
Oct 14 09:48:42 node4 polkadot[24877]: 2022-10-14 09:48:42  ✨ Imported #7735136 (0x81cc…c93f)
Oct 14 09:58:48 node4 polkadot[24877]: 2022-10-14 09:58:48   Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x81cca4dbb445e52a2cd6c329f4fc7c35ebf9cbdca0ab6dd1aee252da8089c93f
Oct 14 09:58:48 node4 polkadot[24877]: 2022-10-14 09:58:48  could not get provisioner inherent data; injecting default data err=ClosedChannelAwaitingInherentData
Oct 14 09:58:48 node4 polkadot[24877]: 2022-10-14 09:58:48   Prepared block for proposing at 7735137 [hash: 0x06a7cdf092dcb5ba8cf7cbdc3c94dce94f3f83fc75110d2e43005edbfb4455b4; parent_hash: 0x81cc…c93f; extrinsics (1): [0x3d39…5756]]
```

How to fix it?

The chain:
http://ws.slonigiraf.org/#/explorer
Telemetry:
https://telemetry.polkadot.io/#list/0x596245dfe0d724c621946ae8b63c3ab850d3bc0f867592857092dc062f49e3e4

Comment: perhaps make title more human readable to get better results.

Comment: The link to your explorer times out. After this error does your chain produce blocks normally?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a bit more context to this issue as it may help you solve the issue.

Looks like the error is coming from the [parachain inherent data provider](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.29/node/core/parachains-inherent/src/lib.rs#L17-L23) logic.

For context on the parachain inherent data provider:

> Parachain backing and approval is an off-chain process, but the
> parachain needs to progress on chain as well. To make it progress on
> chain a block producer needs to forward information about the state of
> a parachain to the runtime. This information is forwarded through an
> inherent to the runtime. Here we provide the
> [`ParachainInherentDataProvider`] that requests the relevant data from
> the provisioner subsystem and creates the the inherent data that the
> runtime will use to create an inherent.

- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/94078b44fb6c9767bf60ffcaaa3be40681be5a76/node/core/parachains-inherent/src/lib.rs#L17-L23

The error is originating from here:

```rust
let inherent_data = match res {
    Ok(pd) => ParachainsInherentData {
        bitfields: pd.bitfields.into_iter().map(Into::into).collect(),
        backed_candidates: pd.backed_candidates,
        disputes: pd.disputes,
        parent_header,
    },
    Err(err) => {
        gum::debug!(
            target: LOG_TARGET,
            %err,
            "Could not get provisioner inherent data; injecting default data",
        );
        ParachainsInherentData {
            bitfields: Vec::new(),
            backed_candidates: Vec::new(),
            disputes: Vec::new(),
            parent_header,
        }
    },
};
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/94078b44fb6c9767bf60ffcaaa3be40681be5a76/node/core/parachains-inherent/src/lib.rs#L90-L110

And the `pd` is not available because of this error:

```rust
receiver.await.map_err(|_| Error::ClosedChannelAwaitingInherentData)
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/94078b44fb6c9767bf60ffcaaa3be40681be5a76/node/core/parachains-inherent/src/lib.rs#L74

Some context on requesting the inherent data:

> When a validator is selected by BABE to author a block, it becomes a
> block producer. The provisioner is the subsystem best suited to
> choosing which specific backed candidates and availability bitfields
> should be assembled into the block. To engage this functionality, a
> ProvisionerMessage::RequestInherentData is sent; the response is a
> ParaInherentData.

- https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot/book/node/utility/provisioner.html#block-production

Answer (score -1):

Check the total amount on stake - if it goes under the  specific limit, the Granpa stops finalizing.

Comment: Care to improve this with reference to why this is the case?